# Defining methods and properties directly or use getters in js

Tags: javascript, performance, getter

I am developing some JS code and have a performance question. Consider that I have a big object which has many methods and properties:

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: 'some value',
  ...
  prop1000: 'some value',
  method1: someMethod,
  ...
  method1000: someMethod,
}
```

[image: first solution]
I guess that if I use getters to fetch each field (prop or method) it will help the runtime engine to load fewer fields in memory when not necessary. For example:

```js
const obj1 = {
  get prop1() { return 'some value'; },
  ...
  get prop1000() { return 'some value'; },
  get method1() { return someMethod; },
  ...
  get method1000() { return someMethod; },
}
```

[image: second solution]
and note that in this scenario I don't need any setter.
So when I use the second solution when I fetch the obj, no fields are fetched automatically until I directly call a getter.
And now the question is, Does the second solution really improve the memory usage and runtime performance, or is it at least a good practice?

Comment: I think that as most of the fields are treated with reference instead of value, the reference call itself will work as the getter you mean and prevents the whole object to enter and leave from the ram any time. And also I think the console.log itself fetches all fields of the obj and it does not necessarily mean that the fields are transporting with object anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance, but I do know that giving a getter is equal to a "lazy rendering" of values. You give the user a function that has only instructions in it. The user then uses it only when he needs, and only when he uses it - data and memory are being used.
Anyway, it's for sure good practice, because it let's you decide which getters you supply and which you don't, and the user should use only what you give him.